# How can I get coins from a personal pool?

Tags: mining-pools

I'm running a node and a private mining pool, does my miner have to solve the block for me to receive any coin?

Comment: Right now, by my math, you would need to have at least 1.2PH/s to average 1 found block per year. So, if you don't have the equivalent of 11 Antminer S19Pro machines, there's a VERY high chance that your miners will be obsolete before you ever complete a block & get paid!

Comment: I am part of some larger pools.  This is me just screwing around at a 512 difficulty trying to catch lightening in a bottle.  Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does.

Pools help reduce the variance in payouts, but aggregated over all your miners, it needs to have enough hashrate to at least find a block occasionally.

Comment: I am part of some larger pools.  This is me just screwing around at a 512 difficulty trying to catch lightening in a bottle.  Thanks for your reply. :)